# Adapter & Theme.Dialog & refreshing content

Tags: android, listview, adapter, imageview

Theres **Activity A** with a ListView using `SimpleCursorAdapter` and for each row, theres a ImageView that should be displayed, according to a column result number in SQLite. Then theres **Activity B** which is a Activity with the `Theme.Dialog`. When i open up the **Activity B** (via startActivityForResult) i have some items, selecting one item, causes the **Activity B** to be finished. So, when i get back to **Activity A**, i can see through the LogCat that bindView is being called but not newView, causing the ImageView to not be refreshed with the new image.

I've tried calling notifyDataSetChanged() in `onResume()` and `onActivityResult()`, since both are called when i get back from **Activity B** but nothing happens!

So, theres a **Activity C** which is a regular Activity that does the same thing as **Activity B**, but its NOT a `Theme.Dialog` Activity, and when i get back from **C** to **A**, newView is being called and thus the ImageView is being refreshed! :D

What should i do?

Comment: Why have you put the imageview setup in newView only? Move it to bindView.

Comment: I didnt. It is only on bindView!

Comment: :( Pentium10 could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

ive worked my way implementing `FilterQueryProvider`. Playing with `runQuery` gave me what i wanted! :)